# Random reboots with Ryzen 1700 + Gigabyte Motherboard + OC'ed RAM

Tags: windows-10, cpu, motherboard, crash, reboot

After getting a new CPU, motherboard, and RAM, I now get random reboots after 1-3 hours of use.

Viewing the Event Viewer gives me `File System Filter 'npsvctrig' (10.0, ‎2097‎-‎07‎-‎25T06:18:05.000000000Z) has successfully loaded and registered with Filter Manager. Event ID: 6` before each reboot.

**Specs:**

- Gigabyte GA-AB350-Gaming-CF Rev 1.0 Motherboard (F4 BIOS)
- Ryzen 1700 Overclocked @ 3.7 GHz 1.35 V
- 16 GB G.SKILL Flare X DDR4 @ 3200 MHz 1.35 V - XMP Profile 1
- EVGA 850 GQ 80+ GOLD, 850W ECO Mode

Comment: I suspect your problems are linked to your memory overclock.  So for the time being disabled it and run at stock frequencies.  You should also update to the current revision of the BIOS firmware.  You should first upgrade to **F5** then to **F6**

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you moved over an existing working install of Windows 10 to this new hardware, which wasn't having problems before.  I'm not certain what the error means.  You can try backing up your files, then performing a Windows Reset.  You can try changing the RAM speeds to standard 2400 MHz speed and see if it's stable there.  If you have a spare HD, try swapping it in, installing a new clean installation of Windows 10, and see if that's stable.